# E: Unable to locate package libpystring-dev

Tags: blender, apt-file

### Context and attempt:

I am trying to [build Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu) within an Ubuntu (20.04) WSL2 terminal. I completed the 'Basic Setup' build instructions, but running the `./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh` command in the 'Advanced Setup' automatic dependency installation instructions yields an error:

```
$ ./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh
WARNING! ****WARNING****
If you are experiencing issues building Blender, _*TRY A FRESH, CLEAN BUILD FIRST*_!
The same goes for install_deps itself, if you encounter issues, please first erase everything in /home/domattioli/src/blender-deps and /opt/lib
(provided obviously you did not add anything yourself in those dirs!), and run install_deps.sh again!
Often, changes in the libs built by this script, or in your distro package, cannot be handled simply, so...

You may also try to use the '--build-foo' options to bypass your distribution's packages
for some troublesome/buggy libraries...


Ran with:
    install_deps.sh



Installing dependencies for DEB-based distribution

Source code of dependencies needed to be compiled will be downloaded and extracted into '/home/domattioli/src/blender-deps'.
Built libs of dependencies needed to be compiled will be installed into '/opt/lib'.
Please edit $SRC and/or $INST variables at the beginning of this script,
or use --source/--install options, if you want to use other paths!

Number of threads for building: 24 (automatically detected, use --threads=<nbr> to override it).
Full install: false (use --with-all option to enable it).
Building OpenCOLLADA: false (use --with-opencollada option to enable it).
Building Embree: false (use --with-embree option to enable it).
Building OpenImageDenoise: false (use --with-oidn option to enable it).

Example:
Full install without OpenCOLLADA: --with-all --skip-opencollada

Use --help to show all available options!

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?y
[sudo] password for domattioli:
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:6 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:7 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [10.5 kB]
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [187 kB]
Hit:14 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2051 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [942 kB]
Fetched 3531 kB in 1s (2388 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done




Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1-dev' instead of 'libfontconfig-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libpystring-dev
ERROR! apt-get failed to install requested packages, exiting.
```

I've updated the path information to address the note for *libfontconfig*, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330068/package-fontconfig-not-found-despite-having-installed-libfontconfig1-dev_)

But following these ['How-To' installation instructions](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/libpystring-dev_1.1.3-2_arm64.deb.html) for *libpystring* also yields an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for domattioli:
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:6 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:8 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 4439 B in 1s (6338 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get install libpystring-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpystring-dev
```

I've tried `sudo apt-file update` prior to the `sudo apt-file search libpystring` command, but nothing is returned;

```
$ sudo apt-file update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Hit:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Get:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:7 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:8 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:13 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 1s (418 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
$ sudo apt-file search libpystring
$
```

### Question Summary:

How do I resolve the `E: Unable to locate package libpystring-dev` error?

#### Edit: Here is the input/output for including the Universe repo:

```
/$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
[sudo] password for domattioli:
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Hit:3 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Hit:6 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Get:7 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 1s (437 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Hit:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Hit:5 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Get:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:8 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 1s (327 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Hit:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Hit:6 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Get:7 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 1s (465 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  InRelease [1575 B]
Hit:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Hit:7 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:8 https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt focal InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Get:10 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B]
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 1s (469 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get install libpystring-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpystring-dev
$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears not. I ran through all of their commands and then tried 
```sudo apt-file search libpystring``` but still nothing returns.

Comment: Edited. Not sure if you are asking me to show the full output from all of the Blender Quick Setup installation questions, though. There were no errors there, but I'm happy to include that output if need be.

Comment: As for the ```focal universe``` discrepancy, I followed all of the instructions for both this [top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/227788/1622151) and the [third answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/430334/1622151). As for ```libpystring-dev```, the command ```sudo apt-file search libpystring-dev``` does not return anything either.

Do I need to start this from scratch somehow?

Comment: Yea I appreciate your help but I think my original question has gotten lost in the muck. I need libpystring-dev to install something else (Blender), but I cannot install nor locate the source code. Even following the [instructions](https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/libpystring-dev_1.1.3-2_amd64.deb.html) yields the same error.

Comment: Yep that's right, andI followed your linked instructions for ```Universe```, without issue, and the locate/install ```libpystring-dev``` issue persists.

Comment: Show us the process of following instructions. Input and output.

Comment: Posted it in the question. Also, could the problem be that the [package site](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libpystring-dev_1.1.3-2_amd64.deb.html) for ```libpystring-dev``` says it's Ubuntu distribution is 22.04 but if I am running 20.04?

Comment: Aw, shucks, YOU ARE RIGHT. It's not available in Ubuntu 20.04. It was added in Ubuntu 22.04. Several spurious comments deleted.