# How to cleanup multiple failed installations?

Tags: 20.04, reinstall, blender, cleanup

I tried a few different times to install Blender in my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 terminal. I think I finally found a [good write-up with instructions](https://techpiezo.com/linux/install-blender-in-ubuntu-22-04/) for a tar.xz file, but when I try to launch it I get anerror:

```
:/usr/include/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64$ blender
/usr/lib/blender/blender: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-6.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I think I might have messed up my environment variable and/or path or something; I assume there should not be two results in the following output to:

```
:/usr/include/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64$ type -a blender
blender is /usr/bin/blender
blender is /bin/blender
```

I'd like to just clean everything up and start anew. How can I do this?

#### Edit

I followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) to update LD_LIBRARY_PATH and now I now longer receive `error while loading shared libraries`. The questions still stands, though, as `type -a blender` still returns two outputs and I'm not sure that is appropriate.

Comment: what method did you use for installation?(like build from source, using package managers, and etc.)

Comment: I approached it from a [few different ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426657/how-to-build-blender-in-ubuntu-20-04-wsl-so-that-i-can-import-bpy-to-python?noredirect=1#comment2484365_1426657). Finally settled on [this](https://techpiezo.com/linux/install-blender-in-ubuntu-22-04/). I'm both a novice, and working on a Windows machine without admin privileges, so it's been tough.

Comment: try ```sudo apt reinstall blender```

Comment: /bin and /usr/bin are really the same these days, with /bin a link to /usr/bin.  Same with /sbin and /usr/sbin, and lib and /usr/lib.